# How to redirect to customer login page in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8, laravel-middleware

I have developed multiauth system with laravel . And I have implemented middleware on routes.

`auth` is for admin and `auth:customer` for customer login. i have implemented these middlewares on routes. so now what I want is on customer route if customer is is not logged in it should redirect on customer login but currently it is redirecting on admin login.

customer routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:customer']], function () {

    Route::get('/customer-read-notification', function () {
        Auth::guard('customer')->user()->unreadNotifications->markAsRead();
        return 1;
    });
   });
```

admin routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/staff-read-notification', function () {
        Auth::user()->unreadNotifications->markAsRead();
        return 1;
    });
 });
```

Comment: Can you show us your custom `customer` middleware?

Comment: not necessary it should  redirect on login page.

Comment: Are you trying to redirect before or after the users have logged in?

Comment: Good practice to put actions within your controllers and not in your routes file.

Comment: Perhaps this could help? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#middleware-parameters